# Match value from one dataframe to values from a second dataframe of different length

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two dataframes like so

```
df_1 <- data.frame(Min = c(1, 4, 9, 25),
                   Max = c(3, 7, 14, 100))

df_2 <- data.frame(Value = c(5, 2, 33),
                   Symbol = c("B", "A", "D"))
```

I want to attach `df_2$Symbol` to `df_1` based on whether or not `df_2$Value` falls between `df_1$Min` and `df_1$Max`.  If there's no `df_2$Value` in the appropriate range I'd like `NA` instead:

```
df_target <- data.frame(
  Min = c(1, 4, 9, 25),
  Max = c(3, 7, 14, 100),
  Symbol = c("A", "B", NA, "D")
)
```

If `df_1` and `df_2` were of equal lengths this would be simple with `findInterval` or something with `cut` but alas...

A solution in either `base` or `tidyverse` would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `cut`: `i = cut(df_2$Value, t(df_1))`; `levels(i)[c(FALSE,TRUE)] = NA`; `df_1$Symbol[i] = df_2$Symbol`. But `data.table` is _much_ more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use a non-equi join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_1)[df_2, Symbol := Symbol, on = .(Min < Value, Max > Value)]

df_1
#   Min Max Symbol
#1:   1   3      A
#2:   4   7      B
#3:   9  14   <NA>
#4:  25 100      D
```

---

Or can use `fuzzy_left_join`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
fuzzy_left_join(df_1, df_2, by = c('Min' = 'Value', 
    'Max' = 'Value'), list(`<`, `>`) ) %>%
   dplyr::select(-Value)
#    Min Max Symbol
#1   1   3      A
#2   4   7      B
#3   9  14   <NA>
#4  25 100      D
```

Comment: This does work, but at the cost of another dependency.  Any ideas for something in `base` or `tidyverse`?

Comment: @Greg fuzzyjoin follows the tidyverse approach.  When you say tidyverse, which all packages should it be included

Comment: Sorry - my bad.  I mean `dplyr`, `tidyr`, `stringr`, `readr`, `forcats`, `tibble` & `purrr`.   Also `ggplot2` if it helps...  The so-called "core" tidyverse packages https://www.tidyverse.org/packages/

Comment: @Greg with those packages, there is no non-equi join.  You may need some loop there.  Not sure if that is what you needed

Comment: Alright, well thanks anyway then, another dependency it is

Comment: Tidyverse certainly is big, but we've already got it, so big + 1 is just that much bigger.